# IOS versions and HTML5 video support

Tags: iphone, html, video, compatibility, mpeg-4

Im new to Stack-Overflow , I have been working on a html5 video application, and I know that IOS 4.2.1 ( iphone 3g , 3gs , and 4g ) Supports the HTML5 video tag in its Safari browser. However I am wondering if the original Iphone (2g) with its IOS 3.1.3 and its Safari is capable of playing HTML5 ( my guess is , it is not ) but I wanted to hear it from you guys, as well as , if its capable of being upgraded to IOS 4.2.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html), the `<video>` & `<audio>` tags are supported in iOS 3.0 onward.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html, iOS has supported HTML5 video since version 1.0.